# get data from url in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have a url of a file **"http://www.example.com/123.aes"**  ( it contains data of a mp3 file with morethan 2MB). Now i want to fetch the data from this url. When i tried http connection to get data, its showing an error - **Requested entity too large**. How to solve this problem ?. 
my code is given below -

```
 try {
    HttpConnection httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(httpURL, Connector.READ, true);
    final int iResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    Dialog.alert(iResponseCode+"");
    InputStream is = httpConn.openInputStream();
    byte[] data = net.rim.device.api.io.IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
    String result = new String(data);
    Dialog.alert(result);

    FileConnection conn = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///store/home/user/pictures/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp3", Connector.READ_WRITE);
    conn.create();
    OutputStream out = conn.openOutputStream();
    out.write(data);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    conn.close(); 
   } catch (IOException e) {
    Dialog.alert(e+"");
    }
```

Also i want to save it as mp3 file in phone memory.

Comment: Check these links, `You have reached the maximum amount of data that can be transferred by the BlackBerry device over a single connection` - btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/KB10264, `http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/HTTP-413-Request-Entity-Too-Large/ta-p/445983` - http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/HTTP-413-Request-Entity-Too-Large/ta-p/445983.

Comment: @Rupak its not working on devises too...

Comment: Sorry, links posted in previous comment weren't answer of the question actually, you can check Hasmukh's answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/13467925/431639.

Comment: @Rupak  iam also getting the same result -> "Requested entity too large".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer -

```
ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;
connDesc = connFact.getConnection(httpURL);
HttpConnection httpConn = (HttpConnection) connDesc.getConnection();
   try {
    httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
    InputConnection inputConn = (InputConnection) httpConn;
    InputStream is = inputConn.openInputStream();
    byte[] data =IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
    Dialog.alert(original.toString());
    FileConnection conn = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///store/home/user/pictures/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp3", Connector.READ_WRITE);
    conn.create();
    OutputStream out = conn.openOutputStream();
    out.write(original);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    conn.close();  
   } catch (IOException e) {
      Dialog.alert(e+"");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you. Try following function:

```
public static String getPage(String url) {    
    String response = "";
    try {
        HttpConnection conn = 
            (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url,Connector.READ_WRITE);
        InputStream input =conn.openInputStream(); 
        byte[] data = new byte[256];
        int len = 0;
        StringBuffer raw = new StringBuffer();
        while( -1 != (len = input.read(data))) {
            raw.append(new String(data, 0, len));
        }
        response = raw.toString();
        input.close();
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
        Dialog.alert(e.toString());
    }
    return response;
}
```

An example call to this function,

```
getPage("yourUrl;deviceside=true;interface=wifi");
```

Comment: iam also getting the same result -> "Requested entity too large"

Comment: when i debug, its showing "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError calling toString" at line StringBuffer raw = new StringBuffer();

Comment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Exceeded-the-limit-of-number-of-bytes-allowed-per-connection/td-p/691141